# Vim remove character from position

Tags: regex, vim, vi, substitution

How can I remove one character from some position ? For example, I have string hello, remove third char and get helo.
I have tried to use next expression, but it doesn't work.

```
.s/\%3c//g
```

Comment: Is it obligatory to use `command mode`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\%c` special atom is a *zero-width* match; i.e. it adds a restriction (on the byte count of the match) **without consuming the character**. To do this, append another atom that consumes it, e.g. `.` for any character match. Then, your substitution will work as expected:

```
.s/\%3c.//g
```

Answer (score 0):

In [normal mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal) also known as [command mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal) but not to confuse with [command-line mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#Command-line), you can type:

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

<kbd>0</kbd>  to go to the start of the line.

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to move 3 characters forward.

<kbd>x</kbd>  to remove the character under the cursor.

Comment: Yes, but this always counts from the beginning of the buffer, whereas `\%c` starts at each line anew. So you solution is only equivalent for the very first line.

Comment: I changed my answer. Now it starts from the begining of the line.

Comment: What you call “command mode” is called “[normal mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal)” by Vim. “Command mode” could be confused with [command-line mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#Command-line).